# How to order search results by category?

Tags: product-list, catalogsearch, ce-1.6.1.0

When performing a search I am wanting to show the results in order of the categories.

I am aware that magento does not allow this natively as products may be in more than one category, however in this example the products **will** belong to either one or the other category.

To clarify, I have only two categories containing complete products, and component products - e.g. rc helicopter, and rc helicopter components to repair or whatever.

I want on the search results for the complete products to be listed first.

On my products/list.phtml file I have added:

```
$_productCollection
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', 'ASC');
```

but this does not appear to work.

Is there a way to do this in the local.xml file? Should I create an observer for the search and add the category order-by there (if so, how should I do that)?

#### Edit

I have also added the following to my local.xml file but also does not work:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>asc</param></action>
        <action method="setSortBy"><param>attribute_you_want_to_use</param></action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
<catalogsearch_advanced_result>
    <reference name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>asc</param></action>
        <action method="setSortBy"><param>attribute_you_want_to_use</param></action>
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to override the core version of `CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php` (copy `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Block/Result.php` into local) and alter the function `setListOrders()`:

```
public function setListOrders()
{
    $category = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
        ->getCurrentCategory();
    /* @var $category Mage_Catalog_Model_Category */
    $availableOrders = $category->getAvailableSortByOptions();
    unset($availableOrders['position']);
    $availableOrders = array_merge(array(
        'category' => $this->__('Category'), //this line
        'relevance' => $this->__('Relevance'),
    ), $availableOrders);

    $this->getListBlock()
        ->setAvailableOrders($availableOrders)
        ->setDefaultDirection('desc')
        ->setSortBy('category'); //this line

    return $this;
}
```